# Azure Mobile Services Identity Column Not Assigned While Offline

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Azure Mobile Services .NET backend with Xamarin.Forms and I'm having an issue with using int identity ID columns. When in an offline scenario, I can successfully add the record to the DB, but the CustomerId column which is an identity remains at 0. Once online, when I sync, the value is set by SQL server and populated on the mobile device.

As the ID is required as I also need to create related data in another table, the question is, how can I get/set an ID for an entity before it's sync'd with the server? I can't set it manually as it may clash with another client. I am suing an existing SQL database, so would prefer not to have to entirely change the scheme to change the ID to use strings or guid's.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        ....
    }

    public async Task SaveCustomer(Customer item) {
        await CustomerTable.InsertAsync (item);
    }
```

Comment: This will require some custom code, at the very least some post push that would replace a placeholder id in your related table (either a client side only column or your entities have a Azure Id column and your normal entity id column.  Native support for relationships & server owned Ifs (requiring id mutation) is not currently built in unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you are mentioning is exactly why Azure Mobile Apps uses strings for IDs.  If you use a string, you can generate a GUID for the ID and use that prior to sync.

The only way to get the Id that is generated by the database is to sync the table.

Comment: Thanks, I feared as much and since posting this have pretty much resigned myself to a huge refactor of Id's to support it. It's a huge hole in the "Using an existing database" scenario on the MSDN website.